# Access files from list in for loop

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I want to calculate the share (%) of pixels classified as 1 from a list of files. For a single image the code works well, however, when I try to write it in a for loop R tells me `named numeric(0)` for all files.
How do I get what I want?

Single Image:

```
ras <- raster("path") # binary product
ras_df <- as.data.frame(ras) # creates data frame
ras_table <- table(ras_df$file) # creates table
share_suit_hab <- ras_table[names(ras_table)==1]/sum(ras_table[names(ras_table)]) # number of pixels with value 1 divided by sum of pixels with value 0 and 1 = share of suitable habitat (%)
print(share_suit_hab)
```

`> ras
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1000, 1000, 1e+06  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 2165.773, 2463.182  (x, y)
extent     : -195054.2, 1970719, 2723279, 5186461  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/name/MASTERARBEIT/BASELINE/Eastern Arctic/Summer_EA_Output/ct/2006/cis_SGRDREA_20060703_pl_a.tif 
names      : cis_SGRDREA_20060703_pl_a 
values     : 0, 1  (min, max)`

For Loop:

```
list_ct <- list.dirs("path")
i=0
for(year in list_ct){
  ct_files_list <- list.files(year, recursive = FALSE, pattern = "\\.tif$", full.names = FALSE)
  ct_file_df <- as.data.frame(paste0("path", i, "/", ct_files_list))
  ct_file_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(ct_file_df), nrow= length(unlist(ct_file_df[1]))))
  ct_table <- table(ct_file_df[, 1])
  stored <- ct_table[names(ct_table)==1]/sum(ct_table[names(ct_table)])
  print(stored)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the final code which is running perfectly!

```
    list_ct <- list.dirs("path", recursive = FALSE)
    stored <- list()

    for (year in seq_along(list_ct)){

      ct_file_list <- list.files(list_ct[year], recursive=FALSE, pattern = ".tif$", full.names = FALSE)
      tmp <- list()

      for (i in seq_along(ct_file_list)){    
        ct_file_df   <- raster(paste0(list_ct[year], "/", ct_file_list[i])) %>% as.data.frame()

        # do calculations

        tmp[[i]] <- sum(ct_file_df[,1], na.rm=TRUE) / length(ct_file_df[!is.na(ct_file_df)[],1])
        names(tmp)[i] <- paste0(list_ct[year], "/", ct_file_list[i])
        print(tmp[i])
      }
      stored[[year]] <- tmp
      names(stored)[year] <- paste0(list_ct[year])

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a reproducible example (data incl.)?

You probably need to replace numeric(0) simply by 0. Numeric(0) does 
not mean 0, it means a numeric vector of length zero (i.e., empty). I'm guessing you're probably assigning numeric(0)+1 which is still a numeric vector of 0.

**Edit:**

You have a folder containing multiple folders which each include 1 or more tif files. You want to loop through each of these folders, importing the tif(s) file, do a calculation, save the result.

In the following, my path contains 5 folders named '2006','2007','2008','2009' and '2010'. Each of these "year"-folders contain an .xlsx file. Each .xlsx file contains 1 column (here, you just need to select the right one in your data frame). This column has the same name in all excel files, "col1", and contains values between 0 and 1. Then this will work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

# 
list_ct <- list.dirs("mypath", recursive = FALSE)
stored <- list()

for (year in seq_along(list_ct)){

  ct_file_list <- list.files(list_ct[year], recursive=FALSE, pattern = ".xlsx$", full.names = FALSE)
  tmp <- list()

  for (i in seq_along(ct_file_list)){    
    ct_file_df   <- read_excel(paste0(list_ct[year], "/", ct_file_list[i])) %>% as.data.frame()

    # do calculations ..

    tmp[[i]] <- sum(ct_file_df$col1) / length(ct_file_df$col1)
    names(tmp)[i] <- paste0(list_ct[year], "/", ct_file_list[i])
    print(tmp[i])
  }
  stored[[year]] <- tmp
  names(stored)[year] <- paste0(list_ct[year])

}
```

Instead of using "read_excel", you just use `raster()` like you did with the single file. Hope you can use the answer.

Comment: I think you are right. To me it looks like the dataframe in the for loop is still just a list of files, but it does not really access the files and do the calculations on the images. I don't know how to add actual data samples here.

Comment: When you import by  `ras <- raster("path") # binary product`, what object is stored in R, and what value does it take?

Comment: @howdidienduphere Perhaps this link could help you a bit? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260218/raster-calculation-loop-r

Comment: Hey Kristian! I edited my post above to show what's stored in `ras`. It's only one band, so I think the problem is just that I don't know how to read in the list of raster files in the right way in the loop. For a single file I simply use `raster("path")`, but  I don't know how to do it with many rasters in the for loop. :)

Comment: @howdidienduphere Could you use the answer, or do you still have problems? :)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think your code would work but where you've got `$col1` I don't know what to put instead, because all my filenames are different. So the column names are different too...

Comment: Then instead of using `ct_file_df$col1` then use `ct_file_df[,1]` if the column you're interested in is column number 1. :)

Comment: Okay GOT IT! I tried that before but forgot to remove the `$`, that's why it didn't work. Haha. THANK YOU SO MUCH! :)  Only problem is now, that it's doing the calculations including NAs. At which point would you exlclude NAs? (My data has only three values. NA=Land Area, 0=unsuitable ocean habitat, 1= suitable ocean habitat. So I need the average share of suitable habitat from the overall ocean habitat per year.)

Comment: You could use `tmp[[i]] <- sum(ct_file_df[,1], na.rm=TRUE) / length(ct_file_df[!is.na(ct_file_df)[],1])`

Answer (score 0):

Example data

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
s <- s > 200
#plot(s)
```

If your actual data is all for the same area (and the raster data have the same extent and resolution, you want to create a `RasterStack` (using the filenames) and use `freq` as below

```
f <- freq(s)
f
#$red
#     value count
#[1,]     0  3975
#[2,]     1  3802

#$green
#     value count
#[1,]     0  3915
#[2,]     1  3862

#$blue
#     value count
#[1,]     0  3406
#[2,]     1  4371
```

Followed by

```
sapply(f, function(x) x[2,2]/sum(x[,2]))
# red.count green.count  blue.count 
#  0.4888775   0.4965925   0.5620419
```

If you cannot make a RasterStack you can make a list and `lapply` and continue as above, or use `sapply` and do this

```
ss <- as.list(s)
x <- sapply(ss, freq)
x[4,] / colSums(x[3:4, ])
#[1] 0.4888775 0.4965925 0.5620419
```

If you insist on a loop

```
res <- rep(NA, length(ss))
for (i in 1:length(ss)) {
  # r <- raster(ss[i]) # if these were filenames
    r <- ss[[i]]  # here we extract from the list
    x <- freq(r)[,2]
    res[i] <- x[2] / sum(x)
} 
res
# 0.4888775 0.4965925 0.5620419
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

This is working perfectly for all files of one year!

`library(raster)
s_list <- list.files("C:/Users/OneDrive - wwfgermany/MASTERARBEIT/BASELINE/Eastern Arctic/Summer_EA_Output/area_calc/ct/2006/", full.names = T)
s <- raster::stack(s_list)
f <- freq(s, useNA = 'no')
f
ct_avg <- sapply(f, function(x) x[2,2]/sum(x[,2]))
ct_avg__mean <- mean(ct_avg)
ct_avg__mean`

However, when I want to write it in another loop, to get one value per year as a final result in the end, I end up with an error saying subscript out of bounds. This is the code I am using:

`setwd("C:/Users/MASTERARBEIT/BASELINE/Eastern Arctic/Summer_EA_Output/area_calc/ct/")
list_ct <- list.dirs("C:/Users/MASTERARBEIT/BASELINE/Eastern Arctic/Summer_EA_Output/area_calc/ct/")
i=0
for (year in list_ct) {
  s_list <- list.files(year, recursive = FALSE, pattern = "\\.tif$", full.names = FALSE)
  s <- raster::stack(s_list)
  f <- freq(s, useNA = 'no')
  f
  ct_avg <- sapply(f, function(x) x[2,2]/sum(x[,2]))
  ct_avg__mean <- mean(ct_avg)
  ct_avg__mean
}`